# Why is Microsoft Edge detecting the wrong language on my site?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I'm creating an Angular web app in English, but when I visit the site using Edge, it thinks my site is in Italian. I have absolutely no idea what would make it think that, and everything I find on the subject is geared towards Edge users changing their settings or translating pages. The end user shouldn't have to change any of their settings; they should never get a message that the site is in Italian in the first place.

How is Edge detecting language, and how can I configure my site so that it detects English? The only thing I know is having `<html lang="en">`, and I have that.

Comment: I have tested that Edge does detect language according to "lang" attribute. Do you have any possible Italian word in your app content?

Comment: No, everything is in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can specify the language via "lang" attribute. Since it doesn't work in this case, I suggest 3 possible workarounds:

1. Try making your `<html>` look like this: `<html lang="en" dir="ltr" xml:lang="en">`
2. Try adding this `<meta>` tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">`
3. If none of the workarounds above solves this issue, you can directly disable the translator prompt via this `<meta>` tag: `<meta name="google" content="notranslate">` **PS: Don't worry because users can still use the translation feature manually.**

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going crazy trying to find an answer. And thank you for providing multiple solutions, it took all three before it stopped trying to translate. I hope this helps someone else in the future too!